# Is it possible to redirect ssh traffic (not forward), How?

Tags: ssh, git, proxy, geolocation

[image]

I am aware that it is possible to forward SSH from server A to server B by creating a tunnel.

What I am asking for is rather the red alternative on the schema above.
Can this scenario be implemented:

1. SSH to server A
2. Server A tells client to go to server B instead
3. Server B communicates directly with client over SSH

So basically a sort of proxy that after introducing the client-server to each other, he gets out of the communication.

I imagine using a firewall redirection doesn't offer much customization.

What I seek ultimately is a way to make access through SSH to git mirrors transparent for client depending on geolocation.

**Advanced scenario scenario**

1. Client Pulling from server A and is closer to server B is redirected to B
2. When pushing, client remains on server A

Comment: Like a redirection rule in a firewall on Server A?

Comment: I don't think this is offered by the standard ssh tools.

Comment: I'd rather try to use HTTP instead of SSH.

Comment: @Tomasz it has to be over SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no flag to turn on in SSH to do this. You'd have to code something custom for GIT. (i.e. if serverA has lower ping time than server B use A or vice vera)

Comment: The target, is to achieve a setup that is transparent for clients.
If i will be doing a customization, i would want it to be on server side

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this kind of wrapping:

- servers, or just the main server holds a git transfer initialisation script
- in the clients, define Git aliases that will get the target server by executing that script on the main server (or any of the servers)

If you only need to redirect `pull`, then you need one alias. But probably you'll also want to redirect `fetch` (if not more commands, I'm not that good with Git).

Comment: I thought about that.
The constraint is that client should be agnostic to the change.
I was hoping for soething similar to http redirect.
Like apache mod_rewrite for http but for ssh.